# How to add jar to java project under linux

Tags: java, linux, shell

i use this shell script to start the java project

```
cd target
echo "shell parameters: $*"
java -classpath . com.tencent.Example $*
```

But now I need to use the jdbc jar,How should I modify the shell script and in which path to put the jar?

Comment: The problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

If the jar is in the current directory,Change the shell to this.

```
cd target

echo "shell parameters: $*"

java -classpath .:./mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar com.tencent.Example $*
```